# How to get all Users and Roles information from Liferay in other applications?

Tags: web-services, service, liferay, liferay-6

I am developing a C# program and I need to show Users and Roles list in it from Liferay database.

Is there any service to fetch these information for me?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Liferay JSON Web Services to get this kind of information (without having to query the DB directly).

If you go to http://your-liferay-server-url.com/api/jsonws you can see all the Web Service end points that Liferay provides, and that you can make calls to.

If you however want to directly query the Liferay database then look at the following tables:

- groups_roles
- groups
- role_
- user_
- users_roles
- usergrouprole

That should be all of the tables in the DB that you need to get the info, and you may not even need all of those tables for what you need.

Comment: This link might also be helpful in getting the WSDL files for the various services liferay offers: http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Liferay+Web+Services+Listing

Comment: Thanks Prakash. Personally I avoid WSDL / XML based web services, but you're right to include it as a alternative.